# Filter email addresses using SugarCRM 9.0 API

Tags: sugarcrm

I am integrating SugarCRM 9.0 using v11 API service. I am struggling quite long now to filter contact's with given email address. As per the new SugarCRM the email addresses of contact are obtained under the field named `email`, which is an array.

Request endpoint: `https://mysugarcrm.org/rest/v11/Contacts/filter`

Input filter array:

```
[
    "filter" => [[
        'email1' => 'test+1@test.com'
    ]]
]
```

Here you can see I am passing `email#` as filter argument which only works for primary email address, but when a contact has more than one email address added to it then how to create the filter? I tried few combinations with the help of sub-expressions `$contains` and `$in` but none of those helped.

For better picture, here is the sample email array than we get in contact record without filter -

```
[
    {
        "id": "c02c12c3-4569-3456-xxxxxxxxx",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "test"
        "email": [
            {
                "email_address": "test@test.com",
                "primary_address": true,
                "reply_to_address": false,
                "invalid_email": false,
                "opt_out": false,
                "email_address_id": "b11h2344-4568-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "email_address": "test+1@test.com",
                "primary_address": false,
                "reply_to_address": false,
                "invalid_email": false,
                "opt_out": false,
                "email_address_id": "b11h2344-4568-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "email_address": "test+2@test.com",
                "primary_address": false,
                "reply_to_address": false,
                "invalid_email": false,
                "opt_out": false,
                "email_address_id": "b11h2344-4568-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "module": "Contacts"
    },
    {
        ....
    },
    {
        ....
    }
]
```

Here you can see, `email` is an array of objects which I want to filter based on email_address.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a solution for this.

There is actually a filter field at behind the picture called `email_addresses`, which we can use to add filter. Here is my new filter array -

```
[
    "filter" => [[
        "email_addresses.email_address":"test@test.com"
    ]]
]
```

So wherever you have to fetch data from the field of type email, use this solution. Works with every module.